# How to move an Image on click in React Native

Tags: javascript, dom, react-native, dom-manipulation

I've recently been learning React Native but haven't really found a way to manipulate the DOM.

I've been trying to make it so that if I click on the TouchableHighlight my Image moves down a couple of px, but I have not managed to get it to move yet and I honestly don't know how to go from here.

My onclick function works since it does return the log every time the button is clicked.

As of now I have this:

```
export default class MainBody extends Component {

  onclick = () => {
    console.log('On click works')
  };

  render() {

    return (

      <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={Style.horList} horizontal={true}>

        <View >

          {/*i need to move this Image down!*/}
          <Image source={require("./img/example.png")}/>
          <View>
            <Text style={Style.peopleInvited}>This is text</Text>
          </View>

          {/*When clicked on this touchable highlight!*/}
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onclick}}>
            <Image source={require('./img/moveImg.png')}/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

      </ScrollView>
}
```

If someone could help me get past this that would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but perhaps the easiest way would be using *states*.

```
class MainBody extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            top: 0 // Initial value
        };
    }
  onclick = () => {
    console.log('On click works')
    this.setState( { top: this.state.top + 5 }) // 5 is value of change.
};


  render() {

    return (

      <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal={true}>

        <View >

          {/*i need to move this Image down!*/}
          <Image style={{top: this.state.top}}source={require("./img/example.png")}/>
          <View>
            <Text>This is text</Text>
          </View>

          {/*When clicked on this touchable highlight!*/}
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onclick}>
            <Image source={require("./img/moveImg.png")}/>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

      </ScrollView>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: That does seem like a really easy and clean way to do it, thanks a lot!